# ASP.NET Access is denied Error message 401.2

Tags: asp.net

Need some help where I am ready to pull my hair out.

I have a site map set up with roles to limit access to pages.  Which is working fine.  But when I click on the link I get Access is denied Error message 401.2

in my web.config gile I have this

```
 <location path="Pages/Sales.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SAL"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

[also here is a screen cap of my folders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4BF5.png)

Let me know if you need to see more.  I am self teaching ASP

Answer (score 0):

Since the web.config is folder specific i think you can leave out the `"Pages/"`.

Change `path="Pages/Sales.aspx"` to `path="Sales.aspx"`

The current definition is for a non existent sub folder called `"Pages"` that contains a page called `Sales.aspx`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and i was able to click the link and the page opened, but now the site map try is showing sales when i no longer has that role.

Comment: @Ken You need to tell the sitemap that only Role="SAL" can see that page

Comment: @Ken where you have `<siteMapNode url="Sales.aspx" title="Sales Page" roles="SAL">`

Comment: @Ken can you select this answer is correct if it helped solve the original issue. Simply click on the 'tick' by the answer.

Comment: Getting a new error, Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  I want roles to be based on the user that is logged in to the computer.  I must be just missing something.

Comment: @Ken that has to do with Windows authentication and not forms authentication for asp.net. I'm not sure how to set that up though.